# William Fractal technical indicator implementation

Tags: python, beginner, pandas

I'm really new to both Python, data analysis and Panda and for gathering a bit of familiarity with this components and trying to replicate a trading strategy I'm creating a function that give me the Wiliam Fractal technical indicator, which by nature is a lagging indicator to apply at the currently analysed row of the dataframe, rather than where it actually happen, but without look ahead bias to not have unrealistic backtesting results ( but also avoiding to go back and always looking for the signal 2 rows before when it actually occurs )

the indicator is defined with this constrains
[source](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fractal.asp)
\begin{aligned} \text{Bearish Fractal} =\ &\text{High} ( N ) > \text{High} ( N - 2 ) \text{ and} \\ &\text{High} ( N ) > \text{High} ( N - 1 ) \text{ and} \\ &\text{High} ( N ) > \text{High} ( N + 1 ) \text{ and} \\ &\text{High} ( N ) > \text{High} ( N + 2 ) \\ \end{aligned}

\begin{aligned} \text{Bullish Fractal} =\ &\text{Low} ( N ) < \text{Low} ( N - 2 ) \text{ and} \\ &\text{Low} ( N ) < \text{Low} ( N - 1 ) \text{ and} \\ &\text{Low} ( N ) < \text{Low} ( N + 1 ) \text{ and} \\ &\text{Low} ( N ) < \text{Low} ( N + 2 ) \\ \end{aligned}
​
which I implemented with the following code:

```
def wilFractal(dataframe):
        df = dataframe.copy()
        df['bear_fractal'] = (
                dataframe['high'].shift(4).lt(dataframe['high'].shift(2)) &
                dataframe['high'].shift(3).lt(dataframe['high'].shift(2)) &
                dataframe['high'].shift(1).lt(dataframe['high'].shift(2)) &
                dataframe['high'].lt(dataframe['high'].shift(2))
        )
    
        df['bull_fractal'] = (
                dataframe['low'].shift(4).gt(dataframe['low'].shift(2)) &
                dataframe['low'].shift(3).gt(dataframe['low'].shift(2)) &
                dataframe['low'].shift(1).gt(dataframe['low'].shift(2)) &
                dataframe['low'].gt(dataframe['high'].shift(2))
        )
    
        return df['bear_fractal'], df['bull_fractal']
```

any suggestions?

usage edit:
The code in this case is used to signal buy signal for a crypto trading bot in this manner:

```
def populate_buy_trend(self, dataframe, metadata) 
    dataframe.loc[
        dataframe['bull_fractal'],
        'buy'] = 1

    return dataframe
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** There was a post (now deleted) about parameterizing the number of shift periods, so I've added a `period` param to both the [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) versions below.

---

### [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) version

1. Instead of making a `copy()` solely to assign result columns, save some overhead by just using standalone Series.
2. Instead of testing `shift(2)` vs `4,3,1,0`, it's more natural to test unshifted vs `-2,-1,1,2`.
3. Instead of chaining `& & &`, it's faster to use a comprehension with [`np.logical_and.reduce()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html).
4. Instead of hardcoding the number of shifts, parameterize it. Although [Investopedia defines this indicator with a period of 2](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fractal.asp), we can add a `period` param (with a default of 2) and generate all `periods` based on that value.

```py
from typing import Tuple

def will_frac(df: pd.DataFrame, period: int = 2) -> Tuple[pd.Series, pd.Series]:
    """Indicate bearish and bullish fractal patterns using shifted Series.

    :param df: OHLC data
    :param period: number of lower (or higher) points on each side of a high (or low)
    :return: tuple of boolean Series (bearish, bullish) where True marks a fractal pattern
    """

    periods = [p for p in range(-period, period + 1) if p != 0] # default [-2, -1, 1, 2]

    highs = [df['high'] > df['high'].shift(p) for p in periods]
    bears = pd.Series(np.logical_and.reduce(highs), index=df.index)

    lows = [df['low'] < df['low'].shift(p) for p in periods]
    bulls = pd.Series(np.logical_and.reduce(lows), index=df.index)

    return bears, bulls
```

---

### [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) version

Alternatively, use [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) to check if the center value in a sliding window is the max (bear) or min (bull):

```py
from typing import Tuple

def will_frac_roll(df: pd.DataFrame, period: int = 2) -> Tuple[pd.Series, pd.Series]:
    """Indicate bearish and bullish fractal patterns using rolling windows.

    :param df: OHLC data
    :param period: number of lower (or higher) points on each side of a high (or low)
    :return: tuple of boolean Series (bearish, bullish) where True marks a fractal pattern
    """

    window = 2 * period + 1 # default 5

    bears = df['high'].rolling(window, center=True).apply(lambda x: x[period] == max(x), raw=True)
    bulls = df['low'].rolling(window, center=True).apply(lambda x: x[period] == min(x), raw=True)

    return bears, bulls
```

---

### Timings

The [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) version is more concise and understandable, but the [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) versions scale much better (memory permitting):

[image: timing rolling() vs shift()]