# count number of rows given column names and values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently switching for R to Python so please be patient with me. Is the following a good way to count the number of rows given column names and values?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["1", "2"], ["2", "4"], ["1", "4"]], columns=['A', 'B'])

cn1 = "A"
cn2 = "B"
cv1 = "1"
cv2 = "2"
no_rows = len(df[(df[cn1]==cv1) & (df[cn2]==cv2)].index)
print(no_rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's a bad idea to input your numerics as strings in your dataframe. Use plain `int`s instead.

Your code currently forms a predicate, performs a slice on the frame and then finds the size of the frame. This is more work than necessary - the predicate itself is a series of booleans, and running a `.sum()` on it produces the number of matching values.

That, plus your current code is not general-purpose. A general-purpose implementation could look like

```
from typing import Dict, Any

import pandas as pd


def match_count(df: pd.DataFrame, **criteria: Any) -> int:
    pairs = iter(criteria.items())
    column, value = next(pairs)
    predicate = df[column] == value
    for column, value in pairs:
        predicate &= df[column] == value
    return predicate.sum()


def test() -> None:
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [[1, 2],
         [2, 4],
         [1, 4]],
        columns=['A', 'B'],
    )

    print(match_count(df, A=1, B=2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `shape[0]` because it's more readable, so in your case it would be:

```py
no_rows = df[(df[cn1]==cv1) & (df[cn2]==cv2)].shape[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

While this specific example can be completely refactored into [Reinderien's top-notch functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270739/238890), we don't always need something so elaborate (e.g., quick exploratory analysis).

Masking and counting come up very often in one form or another, so I think it's still worth reviewing how to do them idiomatically in pandas.

---

#### Revised code

Maintaining the spirit of the original code, I would use something like:

```
matches = df[cn1].eq(cv1) & df[cn2].eq(cv2)
len(df[matches])  # but remember that matches.sum() is faster
```

---

#### Comments on the original code

```
len(df[(df[cn1] == cv1) & (df[cn2] == cv2)].index)
^               ^       ^                  ^
3               2       4                  1
```

1. No need to use `.index` explicitly since [`DataFrame.__len__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/04b538a55365b5d1ae930687a91bb3ac4ea53040/pandas/core/frame.py#L1410-L1414) does it automatically:

   > ```
   > class DataFrame(NDFrame, OpsMixin):
   >     ...
   >     def __len__(self) -> int:
   >         return len(self.index)
   > ```
2. [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) can sometimes be useful over `==`:

   - supports `axis` / `level` broadcasting
   - arguably more readable when joining multiple tests

     ```
     df[cn1].eq(cv1) & df[cn2].eq(cv2) # (df[cn1] == cv1) & (df[cn2] == cv2)
     ```
   - arguably more readable when chaining methods (e.g., when [comparing shifted columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68611243/13138364))

     ```
     df[cn1].shift().eq(cv1).cumsum() # (df[cn1].shift() == cv1).cumsum()
     ```
3. If speed is important, `len(df)` is faster than `df.shape[0]` ([h/t @root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943975/13138364)):

   [image]
4. If you have a *lot* of conditions to join (e.g., [generated via comprehension](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/259718/238890)), consider `np.logical_and.reduce`:

   ```
   df[np.logical_and.reduce([
       df[cn1] == cv1,
       # ...
       df[cn2] == cv2,
   ])]
   ```